# Form won't submit in chrome

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome

I have a `<form>` in my html page, which submits without problems in IE or Anonymous mode in Chrome.  But it doesn't submit in classic mode of Chrome.

The submit button is completely ignored and nothing happens. I tried deleting history, cache etc. and it did not help.

My code:

```
Login:
<form method="post" name="loginForm" action="stranky/login.php">
 <div style="margin-left:20px;">
  Name:<br> <input type=text name="name"><br>
  Password:<br> <input type=password name="pswd">
 </div>
 <input type="submit" onClick="this.form.submit()" class="smallButton" value="Log in">
</form>
```

As you can see, I even tried `onClick="this.form.submit()"` which also did not help.
I have tried also without "onclick".
**EDIT:** On local computer it works with both browsers, but uploaded on the server it works only with IE. Maybe something is wrong with the website hosting?
**SOLUTION** AVG cleaned my PC and it started working, perhaps it was some kind of virus

Comment: Try "onclick" instead of "onClick"

Comment: You shouldn't need the `onclick` as the default action of a `<input type="submit">` **is** to submit

Comment: Don't update your question with the solution... either add your own answer, or delete the question (as it was a local issue, and nothing to do with your code).

Answer (score 2):

Either remove the `onlick` handler, or replace the `type="submit"` with `type="button"` inside the button, the both conditions are ambiguous.

The the default action of a submit button is to submit the `form`, as described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html).
Also you can try to submit the form **by pressing the Enter key** and see if the problem still exists.

If so, then you must **disable all** Chrome plugins and extensions and try again. Most probably something interfere with the page's forms (or perhaps you are infected with Trojan horse - it is normal "*weird*" behavior when it happens).

Comment: When I said "I even tried" it means I tried it without the onclick before.

Comment: I had a similar problem -- I opened the page in an incognito window in Chrome, and the form submitted properly. It was probably an extension that caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are your catching your form with JS or PHP?
Try giving a name to your submit button name="btnSubmit", in PHP you can catch it via $_POST["btnSubmit"]. In JS via $("input[name='btnSubmit']").on("click", myFunction).

Login:

```
<form method="post" name="loginForm" action="stranky/login.php">
   <div style="margin-left:20px;">
      Name:<br> <input type=text name="name"><br>
      Password:<br> <input type=password name="pswd">
   </div>
   <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="smallButton" value="Log in">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was just a local PC problem, code was fine

Comment: I have an isolated incident like this. Its working in all machine except in one of my team members Windows/Chrome machine. Curious what was the problem ?